# Expression in mysql order by not being evaluated

Tags: mysql

This problem began when I was trying to set the `order by` column from a bound statement.
This is not working for me:

```
select * from testTable order by field(?, 'userid','name') asc;
```

The field() function is not being evaluated for some reason.

After further investigation I found that this also does not work:

```
select * from testTable order by (1+1) asc
```

Are these both the same problem? And what is the solution?

Comment: Can you show us what your desired output is?  You might be using the wrong approach here.

Comment: Both do not make sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, what does the `?` represent in your first query?  Is that supposed to be a column?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but I think it is plausible that you can't use `ORDER BY #ColumnIndex` (For example `ORDER BY 2`) when you are using `SELECT *`.

Try specifying all the columns you are willing to select, or use column names in the order by clause.